# Authorize a trustilne for an account before a trustline is set up

Tags: trustline

Is there a mechanism for an asset issuer to authorize a trustline to a wallet before the wallet establishes a trustline?

Use case: Bob wants to hold a regulated asset. This asset requires authorization by the issuer. He is on my platform and asks to allow one of his wallets to hold asset A. His wallet is managed outside of my platform. This is basically a request to whitelist a wallet to hold the asset.

Do we have to ask the end user to first establish a trustline everytime? The main challenge here is that if the users wallet was managed by our system we can help the user set up a trustline first. If the wallet is an external wallet, it would be nice to allow this whitelisting/authorize call to happen without depending on them to set up a trustline initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the answer is no.  Even if an issuer creates a [Claimable Balance](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/claimable-balance/) for an `auth_required` asset, the claimant still needs an authorized trustline before they can claim it.

There is a proposal to preauthorize trustlines, but it hasn't been implemented yet.  See:

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/core/cap-0032.md

Comment: Thanks for sharing the proposal!